# Using Control.OldException in newer ghc

Tags: haskell, exception

Is there a way of using [Control.OldException](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.2.0.1/docs/Control-OldException.html) in newer ghc (>= 7.6.2) ?

I basically need them for one of the RWH [chapter](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/concurrent-and-multicore-programming.html) which uses lot of those type signatures including the type `Exception`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to translate the old code to the new base instead. For example, use `SomeException` instead of `Exception`. There's actually only one point where `Threw` and therefore `Exception` would be used:

```
    result <- try body
    putMVar state (either Threw (const Finished) result)
```

Note that you cannot derive `Eq` in `ThreadStatus` any longer, since `SomeException` isn't an instance of `Eq`:

```
data ThreadStatus = Running
                  | Finished
                  | Threw SomeException
                    deriving (Show)
```

#### Minimal example

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
import Data.Maybe (fromJust)
import Control.Exception (SomeException, try, throw, Exception)

-- other code and imports stay the same, with the exception of ThreadStatus:

data ThreadStatus = Running
                  | Finished
                  | Threw SomeException
                    deriving (Show)

-- all thread manager functions stay the same

instance Exception String -- just for demonstration

main = do
  man <- newManager
  tid  <- forkManaged man (throw "Oh no, an exception happened")
  m <- waitFor man tid
  case fromJust m of
    Threw e -> putStrLn . show $ e
    _       -> return ()
```